# How could " possibly be the returned value for a new user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form that I am trying to implement that creates a new user in the database. For some reason when it executes the controller function its returning " for the email address and returns me back to the view with a UserManager validation error. But I dont possibly see how it could be returning " when I can see its posting the email from the view.

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Rabbit.Application.Models;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Rabbit.Application.Identity.Models;
    
    namespace Rabbit.Application.Identity.Controllers
    {
       
        public class AdminController : Controller
        {
            private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    
            public AdminController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> usrMgr)
            {
                _userManager = usrMgr;
            }
    
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                return View(_userManager.Users);
            }
    
    
            public ViewResult Create() => View();
    
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Create(User input)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var appUser = new ApplicationUser
                    {
                        UserName = input.Name,
                        FirstName = input.FirstName,
                        LastName = input.LastName,
                        Email = input.Email,
    
                    };
    
                    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, input.Password);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                            //if (error.Code == "DuplicateUserName") continue;
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                    }
                }
                return View(input);
            }
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using Rabbit.Application.Models
@model User
  @section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial"/> 
}
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<h1 class="bg-info text-white">Create User</h1>
<a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

<form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Create" method="post">

                  <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">
                                    <i class="ni ni-circle-08"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <input asp-for="Email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="email" />

                        </div>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block"></span>
                    </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">
                                    <i class="ni ni-circle-08"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />

                        </div>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block"></span>
                    </div>
                   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and check which return statement is executed when the user is successfully created?

Comment: The user is never successfully created. UserManger validation pops it when I click create and the output indicates I entered an invalid email address “ and takes me back to the form with the UserManager error. If I put other validations on it they recognize it as a string and the string I entered.

Comment: What's the error from user manager? Are you entering the correct value for email? What's the value you have in `input.Email`? Is your view bound to a model type? Can you share view code?

Comment: Invalid Email Address. But I can see the payload sending the test@gmail.com user to the server. If I create my own validations I can change the email to be funky and it recognizes my changes and when I enter a correct email address or not, but UserManager does not. 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager: Warning: User validation failed: InvalidEmail.

Comment: I added the view to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was causing " to be entered but I recoded the routing through the controller and everything started working normally. I believe it was trying to load the post method and bypass the initial call for `Create()=> View();`
This was likely due to being new and not fully understanding routing and was receiving bogus results that would likely be very difficult to track down. Once I took a step back to learn more about how the controller and model work in conjunction with the view from a routing aspect I was able to get everything I was doing working correctly.